# What's wrong with this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

What's wrong with this SQL query .. it keeps giving me an error .. and the error is also noted below

here's the query :

```
UPDATE Politicians SET Big Fan = Big Fan +3 WHERE ID = '2' 

 MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Fan = Big Fan + 3 WHERE ID ='2'' at line 1
```

Comment: I would recommend that you do not use spaces in your column or table names.

Comment: Me too. Or keywords, massive PIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you just found out why spaces in table and column names are a PIA

guessing but

```
UPDATE Politicians SET `Big Fan` = `Big Fan` +3 WHERE ID = '2'
```

Assuming Politicians has a column called Big Fan, mysql is seeing the word big and the word fan, neither of which it understands.

Wrapping in backticks, makes it see it as one "word" and then it knows you are referring to a column in the Politicians table

Comment: "mysql is seeing the word big and the word fan, neither of which it understands." --- that's incorrect. If you check the error message you'll see that it's the syntax error and mysql fails on "fan" token, with "big" token parsed

Comment: @zerkms. It is not parsed. It's the point where the parser ran out of allowable options.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: "neither of which it understands." --- parser only builds an AST. So it "understands" `Big`, but doesn't understand `Fan`. You're wrong in the part "neither of which". For syntactic analysis/parsing the `Big` **is** a valid token, but the `Fan` **is not**. Actually that's why the error message looks like: "for the right syntax to use near 'Fan = Big Fan + 3" -- note that it starts with `Fan`, the first invalid token that doesn't fit mysql's sql grammar

Comment: I'm all for being pedantic when necessary, but in this cas it isn't is it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use backticks when you have spaces in your column names:

```
UPDATE Politicians SET `Big Fan` = `Big Fan` +3 WHERE ID = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the space in the column name.

```
UPDATE Politicians SET `Big Fan` = `Big Fan` +3 WHERE ID = '2'
```

Comment: @zerkms Just realized that I was rushing to get my answer in

Answer (score 0):

You are missing square brackets. Try this

```
UPDATE Politicians SET [Big Fan] = [Big Fan] +3 WHERE ID = '2'
```

Comment: that would be access / sql server

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a space in your MySQL table name. I believe you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE `Politicians` SET `Big Fan` = `Big Fan` + 3 WHERE `ID` = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not have space in the column name. Rather have "-" or underscore. Now if you have space then you can use 'Column Name' for this case.

Comment: Single quotes are for delimiting string literals in mysql